# How to create custom JSF component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a basic knowledge of JSF. I want to create a custom graphic chart similar to PrimeFaces. I need information how this can be done with Ajax.
My idea is to create a graphic chart which is visually updated every 5 seconds. Could you give me some information about that, please?

Comment: This is really a broad question. I can almost write a book as an answer. Just go through a self-respected JSF book/tutorial (the online Java EE tutorial has chapters on the subject) and whenever you stucks at a specific step, ask a more specific question.

Comment: I need ajax component which makes synchronous calls. This component(I suppose) I can use to implement the JQuery progress bar or to make self-updatable charts. Maybe the if it's possible the best way will be to modify `h:ajax` tag to reload automatically for example every 3 seconds?